# eror when get eclipse : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error

Tags: java

I created a new java project in Eclipse, then created a new class in it and write this codes in it:

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        system.out.println("hello world");
    }
}
```

This problem occurres when I run my project:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    system cannot be resolved
    at helloworld.main.main(main.java:7)
```

Comment: It's `System`, not `system`.

Comment: @FelixGerber Please resist from adding unrelated tags. And _yes_, the eclipse tag is unrelated, because OPs problem will appear in every IDE, not only in eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

Java is case sensitive and correct spelling of system is `System` not `system`

Answer (score 2):

```
   package helloworld;
   public class main {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           System.out.println("hello world");
       }
   }
```

Changing your code to this should fix your Problem.

A Little hint: Always fix your compilation problems. Eclipse show them to you with red underlined as you can see here:

[image]

Eclipse also warns you if you try to start an porject within erros. (except your disabled it). Don't ignore those warnings.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hello @Felix Gerber, I just saw this edit suggestion: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10344113  . I would like to point out that on SO, salutations are considered noise and should be removed from posts, not added to them. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) for the relevant discussion. Kind regards!

Comment: @S.L.Barth Ohhh okay I will have a look at it, thanks!